# Woocommerce - Display only products with a certain custom field in the cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I am trying to only display items in the cart that have a certain custom attribute. But I can not find an action hook that would allow me to only show the items in the cart that have this property. For example if I add 4 items into my cart but only 2 of the items have this property, then when I visit the cart page I would want to only see the total for the 2 items with the property.

Also I know I can not allow them to add to cart if it doesn't have that certain custom attribute but I can not take that approach. They must be able to add all items to their cart.

Comment: What is the use case for adding an item to the cart, but not being able to see it in the cart? That seems deceptive, and one of the few things I'd probably classify as not possible. Either it's in the cart or it isn't. Though your question text mentions wanting to get the total for only the special products. That's different from what you mention in the title, so can you clarify which are you asking about?

Comment: I figured this question would come up. I have currently created two cart pages for the user. Depending on what type of product they add to the cart. The item goes into both carts. But when I get the cart items if they are on the regular cart page it should show the regular items. If they are on the special cart page it should show the items with the custom attribute.  I am able to calculate the totals based off the attribute. But not able to show or hide the item.

Comment: @AdrianBegi can you include the details of how you have 2 carts? how did you implement it? more than two carts in woocommerce is kinda tricky to do, as far as I know... if you can show that, I might be able to help...

Comment: I have two cart pages. Not necessarily two cart session variables. One is the regular woocommerce cart template and then I have a custom cart page I would only show these specific items. Does that make sense ?

Comment: I get your idea and intention... but I'm doubtful if you know that if ever you get this implemented, you can only have one success checkout with these carts... session for cart will reset after checkout...

Comment: Ahh good point I didn't even think about the fact that the cart gets wiped after any one checkout. Looks like I have to take another approach. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: I usually say most everything is possible in WordPress with enough time and resources, but I agree with Reigel, this doesn't seem possible to me either. Between the individual items being removed from the cart and the whole cart being emptied on checkout, working around all that could be a Sisyphean task.